# Need to Align Element with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap form where I need to fix two element alignment. Screenshot show the current look of the form http://s27.postimg.org/j8h3d0203/screen2.png  by using the following markup

```
<fieldset class="col-md-8">
                                        <div class="form-group">

                                            <label for="BI16" class="col-md-4 control-label">Visual Acuity L:20/:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                            <label for="BI16" class="col-md-2 control-label">R: 20/</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div>
                                                <yesno-button button1="yes" button2="no" id="B19" value1="BV8" value2="BV9"></yesno-button>
                                                <label for="B19" class="radio-inline control-label">
                                                    Creative Lens Used?
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div>
                                                <yesno-button button1="yes" button2="no" id="B20" value1="BV6" value2="BV7"></yesno-button>
                                                <label for="B20" class="radio-inline control-label">
                                                    Will the patient consent to an End of Life Planning discussion?
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div>

                                                <label for="B12" class="col-md-2 control-label">Comments:</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    <input type="text" id="B12" class="form-control" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which form do you want to align? You can use

`<p class="text-left">Left aligned text.</p>
 <p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
 <p class="text-right">Right aligned text.</p>
 <p class="text-justify">Justified text.</p>`